# Что означает p в командной строке Ruby

Tags: ruby

Есть такая строчка:

```
ruby -e "p 'hello world!'"
```

Что означает p в Ruby? Какое полное название p?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод `p()` [содержится в модуле ядра Kernel](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-p) и выводит в стандартный поток с новой строки результат вызова [`obj.inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-inspect) переданного ему объекта.

То есть в данном случае он берет объект `'hello world!'`, вызывает его метод `inspect` который вернет строковое представление(такое же `'hello world!'`) и выводит его с новой строки в стандартный вывод.